# Query not working searching between dates

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, php-carbon

my query is not working, basically im trying to get records between dates_time but for some reason is not working, i already checked on my db and should return one result. Im using Carbon and Eloquent from Laravel.

```
$todayFictitiasDate = new Carbon("2017-08-09 16:00:00");

//records between 2017-08-09 17:00:00 and 2017-08-09 21:00:00

$liveMatches = SoccerMatch::where('date_time','>=', $todayFictitiasDate->addHour())
                        ->where('date_time','<=',$todayFictitiasDate->addHours(5))
                        ->get();
```

I also tried this way:

```
 $liveMatches = SoccerMatch::whereBetween('date_time',array($todayFictitiasDate->addHour(),$todayFictitiasDate->addHours(5)))
            ->get();
```

My record on db:

```
id= 1
title =  something
date_time = 2017-08-09 18:00:00
```

Works this way but dont no why:
For some reason the datetime keeps adding hours when i isnert on eloquent, dont no why, it works this way:

```
$n  = (new Carbon("2017-08-09 16:00:00"))->addHour();
$n5 = (new Carbon("2017-08-09 16:00:00"))->addHours(5);

$liveMatches = SoccerMatch::whereBetween('date_time',array($n,$n5))
            ->get();
```

Comment: Look up `whereBetween()`

Comment: What's the result of `dd($todayFictitiasDate->addHour());`?

Comment: already tried it this way whereBetween @RiggsFolly i updated my answer

Comment: @RiggsFolly i updated by question

Comment: The problem is that you are comparing two objects and not two datetime strings. Try to use `$n->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')` in the comparison array. It will work this way.

Comment: _For some reason the datetime keeps adding hours when i isnert on eloquent_ Probably because this is in a loop